# Detecting the presence of a black areas in a grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

My objective is a vague one, and as such I don't have any reproducible code for the same.

I want to develop a network that I train with certain types of grey scale images that will detect the areas which are above a certain grayscale intensity threshold.

How should I proceed further with this? Do I need a neural network for this?

Below are some sample images. The one on the extreme left is what it should look like, the one in the middle is when it finds out that there are some black lines (not exactly black, but above some threshold of a grayscale intensity) and the one on the extreme right is what I expect the output of my code to be.

PS This is particularly of interest when detecting cracks in CT scans, which show up as dark black blobs/lines among the other grayscale background

[image]

Comment: Its too vague, you can probably add a few sample images. This link might give you some direction - http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html

Comment: what do you need a network for? if your goal is a global threshold just apply one.

Comment: Add some sample images of what is ok and what is not ok and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: Black areas will be represented by **low** numbers in images, as they have low brightness or intensity, so you probably want to detect items **below** a threshold. You probably don't need a neural network for this, but you will need some more representative images.

Comment: Why I though of having a network was because if there is another scan of another body part, the shape of the crack will change and so it may not be a line but instead maybe small squares then that should be detected as well, since it will still be blacker than the remaining background.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to discuss the processing of unknown images just by description. provide actual image examples or delete your post

Comment: @vedantgala As long as the intensity of the crack does not change the treshhold will still yield the same result independent of the body part that is scanned.

Comment: [A or B](https://i.imgur.com/q4zZI36.png) ? If (A) - you need a line segment detection instead

Comment: The proper deep learning network architecture for this is a single layer, one intput and one output, that you apply to each pixel in turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very trivial and you will definitely not need a neural network to solve this. If you are working with grayscale images and know the intensity threshold you are interested in (e.g you allow an intensity value up to 3) you can just do a simple threshold operation to identify the black regions.

This would probably also work on your ct scan application, presupposed these "cracks" are always of very low intensity.

E.g. for a ct-image where I applied your "cracks" in your example image, threshold these cracks would work pretty well (you only get some background noise/artifacts). See the following OpenCV snipped:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('chest-ct-lungs.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,3,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('output.png',thresh)
```

**input:**

[image]

original image source: www.radiologyinfo.org

**output:**

[image]

As you see this is literally just 3 lines of code, don't always assume you **have to** use neural networks for everything, sometimes its best to just solve a image-processing problem the "old fashioned way". Especially if the problem is a trivial one.

Comment: Any idea how I could get those red boxes around the lines and leave those lines on the same image as before?

Comment: @vedantgala Calculate the inverse binary image instead (use the option `THRESH_BINARY_INV`), then calculate the countours for this image using `findContours`. Use the `boundingRect` function to calculate the bounding boxes for each of your contours and finally draw them onto your original image. There should be plenty of tutorials on how to do this using OpenCV.